# Flask on GAE - Connect to Google API - Can't use JSON file

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-api

I'm fairly new to Flask, GAE and the use of API. I'm trying to build a basic Web App that can connect to one of Google's API.

My folder structure looks like this (I've kept it to the main files):
app-webemotions:
-app.yaml
-main.py
-lib
--sentimentanalysis.py
-static
--credential.json

Everything is working but providing the json file for the credentials. My understanding is that there's a couple of ways to do it:
1) Setting up the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable to the destination of my file in app.yaml
2) Requesting the file through my script (sentimentanalysis.py)

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to make any of those work.

**Option 1):**
In app.yaml I have the line:

```
env_variables:
   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: static/key/credentials.json
```

I then run my code through dev_appserver.py . and get the following error:

```
ApplicationDefaultCredentialsError: File static/key/credentials.json (pointed by GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable) does not exist!
```

**Option 2):**
I have a line of code in my script sentimentanalysis.py:

```
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('/static/credentials.json', scope)
```

And when running the code I get the following error:

```
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, 'file not accessible', filename)
IOError: [Errno 13] file not accessible: '/static/credentials.json'
INFO     2016-08-06 04:10:51,678 module.py:788] default: "POST /Sentiment-analysis HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

**Question:**
So it looks like regardless of the method I'm using, I'm not able to provide the right path to the JSON file

My question is to know first if any of the above options is the right option and if yes, what am I doing wrong? If they are not the right options, what would you recommend?

Apologies if this has already been asked, I've tried to find an answer for a few hours now and haven't been able to crack it...

Thank you!

Comment: Code can't access static resources unless you explicit allow it,  have a read of the docs.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Well I had a read of the documents, otherwise I wouldn't be posting :) I am unsure what you mean by "static resources". I have a static folder, with static resources such as CSS or JS files. All those can be accessed by my App, only the JSON file can't. Can you please clarify? Thank you.

Comment: When you say the static resources can be accessed by your app do you really have flask code explicitly opening the these files, or do you mean a web browser can load these files.  

You aren't clear and there is a big difference - hence my original comment.

The specific documentation I am referring to is https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref#handlers_element  and the directive "application_readable".

You should probably include your app.yaml

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks again. I think I originally didn't make the difference between "read by your application" VS "served to the end user" and was assuming my application could "read" the file. In the end, I changed my approach and used my API Developer key to pass on the right information as opposed to the JSON file. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running on Google App Engine, then your code automatically has the credentials it needs.  Do not set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS and do not call .from_json_keyfile_name.  Instead, call:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
```

As shown here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/bigquery/api/getting_started.py

Comment: Hi Jeffrey. Thanks also for your response! I ended up using my API Developer key within the code which works but will try your suggestion. I was under the assumption that 'credentials' in that situation would go search your credentials in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS hence why I was trying desperately to pass on the file! However it makes sense now so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=credentials.json
use this command if you are using cmd